# LinqToSQL Retrieved Entity being inserted as new Entity

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I have a c# app that is doing database work using LinqToSQL.

I have 2 tables in my sql database that are set up like so

> Table 1 - Name = Log
>
> > Columns - Id (Int NOT NULL IDENTITY), DefectId (Int NOT NULL), Stage (Int NOT NULL)
>
> Table 2 - Name = Defect
>
> > Columns: Id (Int NOT NULL IDENTITY), Name (NVarChar(50) NOT NULL)

Table 2 has a relationship to table 1 via a OneToMany relationship. So one DEFECT Entity to Many LOG Entities.

The Association Editor in VS 2012 for the relationship is like so

> Parent Class = Defect | Child Class = Log
>
> Association Properties
>
> Defect Properties = Id | Log Properties = DefectId

Ok so that's the setup. My problem is that if I create a new `LOG` Entity like so

```
Log L = new Log();
```

then retrieve a `DEFECT` entity and assign it to the DEFECT property of L, like so.

```
var d = (from def in DatabaseContext.DEFECT
         where def.Id == 1
         select def).Single();

L.DEFECT = d;
```

Now if I insert `L` into the database it also inserts `L.DEFECT` as a new entity which means I get duplicates.

Somewhere I have got the setup wrong or a property set wrong so I am asking does anyone know what I have done wrong or things I can check.

I use MS SQL MANAGMENT STUDIO to look at and modify the database.
I used MSLinqToSQLGenerator in vs 2012 to generate the mappings etc in my project.

Although I have work with sql and LinqToSQL a few times in other projects I'm still a newbie so my terminology may be wrong which I do apologise for.

UPDATE: The insert code

```
using (dbTechLogDataContext db = new dbTechLogDataContext())
{
    db.Logs.InsertOnSubmit(L);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: You're not showing use the context usage, which could be helpful.

Comment: Try just setting the DefectID on the log, instead of assigning the Defect to the log directly.

Comment: @joeBrunscheon: no no no, that is completely against the ORM/linq2sql way of working.

Comment: I know it SHOULD work the way he has it implemented, but that's how EF does things with navigational properties. Setting the DefectID on the log and saving the changes would accomplish the task and allow the database to enforce the foreign key constraints.

Comment: @JoeBrunscheon If I step through I am seeing the Id of the DEFECT being changed just before the insert. But as Pleun says, I shouldn't be changing the id myself so I wonder why LinqToSQL is changing the entity to a New entity?

Comment: Put the code that selects the Defect in the same dbContext using statement as the one that you use to insert the Log.

Comment: What happens if you do the insert with the same datacontext and not with a new one.

Comment: I'm currently not at work which is where Im working on this project but Joe and Pleun, that's a good point! I will try that first thing.